# template paramater - pointer to templated type

Tags: c++, function, templates

Considering this example:

```
template< typename T, T &V>
void doSomething() {
    V = 1;
}

int i;
double d1, d2;

int main() {
    doSomething< int, i>();
    doSomething< double, d1>();
    doSomething< double, d2>();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to eliminate type names in the invocations? Something like this:

```
    doSomething< i>();
    doSomething< d1>();
    doSomething< d2>();
```

Note that the function signature shouldn't change. You still have to be able to use it as this:

```
typedef void (*THandler)();

THandler handlers[] = {
    &doSomething< int, i>,
    &doSomething< double, d1>,
    &doSomething< double, d2>
};
```

Comment: A side note: In C++ `void main()` is an invalid signature for `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T& V) {
    V = 1;
}
```

but you use it this way:

```
doSomething(i);
doSomething(d1);
doSomething(d2);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since the proposed solution changes the method signature. The purpose is to have the function bound to the values being changed at compile time. So that they may be put into an array of function pointers.

Comment: @Sergey: Then the answer is no. It can't be done. Type deduction for template functions are based on function arguments.